# C strtoul() bug for large values in AtmelStudio

Tags: c, type-conversion, avr, atmega

I need to convert a large character number to a long to program my Atmega8 chip on AtmelStudio.

I tried using `atol()` and `strtoul()` and it does not work. I've read on google that there is a bug with `strtoul()` which only allows to use smaller values. I tried and it's true. I can convert the char "250" to a long with `strtoul()` but not "5555".

I've read that the fix is to make your own strtoul() function but how do I do that? I don't know the implementation of `strtoul()`, it's an extern in the library.

This does not work:

```
char *my_time = "2505";      
unsigned long new2 = (unsigned)strtoul(my_time, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know, I am doing embedded programing, I dont have a printf. From what I see, it looks like it returns 0.

Comment: So what is the question, please?

Comment: So to clarify, you're saying that these functions are buggy in *your implementation* of the C library, yes?

Comment: Since I removed my previous comment, I repost it: *How* does it not work? What does the function return? If you pass a valid pointer as the second argument what is it set to? And regarding your lack of `printf` you must have *some* way of communicating with the system? Like a serial port at least? Many embedded systems send text on `stdout` (like what happens when you use `printf`) to the serial port.

Comment: @alk Why am I not able to convert "2505" to a long with strtoul()?

Comment: And do *try* without the casting, it's not needed as [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) should be declared to return the correct type anyway.

Comment: "*I've read on google that there is a bug ....*" you surely did not read this on google, but on a page linked by google. Which pages has this been? However **if** there is a bug in the implementation you use you now know  why it does not work using your implementation.

Comment: 1) Do you need to detect conversion overflow?  2) drop the `(unsigned)` cast in `(unsigned)strtoul(my_time, NULL, 10);`  It serves no purpose and _could_ be your problem if `unsigned` is unconventionally 8-bit.

Comment: "_I've read on google that there is a bug ...._". Are you talking about that bug that was fixed on 2003?

Comment: How exactly do you *know* that `new2` is not set to `2505`?

Comment: I use the converted value to turn on a debugging LEDS this amount of time in ms

Comment: Maybe `strtoul(my_time, NULL, 10);` is working correctly but the function that accepts  the "value to turn on a debugging LEDS" only handles 8-bit?

Comment: No. I tested this function. Anyways. It's working now. I have accepted the answer

Comment: I just tested your example. It works perfectly fine with the `strtoul()` of avr-libc 1.8.0. And the implementation has not changed since 2003. Are you using an antique avr-libc?

Comment: I dont't know. How do I verify that?

Comment: The libc version number is macro-defined in [avr/version.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__version.html).

Comment: "1.8.0" too, how did you test it? @EdgarBonet

Comment: With an Arduino Uno, putting something like `Serial.println(new2);` right after your example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of converting an (unsigned) decimal string to an integer is:

```
unsigned long str2int(const char *s)
{
  unsigned long x = 0;
  while(isdigit(*s))
  {
    x *= 10;
    x += *s++ - '0';
  }
  return x;
}
```

It's really not very complicated, it just walks through the digits, building up the value as it goes. The `*s++ - '0'` is perhaps a sign of me failing to rein in my "experienced C programmer's maximum terseness syndrome". Also I was in kind of a hurry. A more clear approach might be:

```
while(isdigit(*s))
{
  x *= 10; /* Each new digit makes the old ones worth more. */
  const int digit = *s - '0'; /* Convert digit character to small int. */
  x += digit; /* Add the current digit. */
  ++s;
}
```

So for instance, consider an input of `"432"`. It would be computed as something like ((0 * 10 + 4) * 10 + 3) * 10 + 2.

Since you're working on an 8-bit microcontroller, you can probably gain a lot of code space by limiting yourself to `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned long`, if your application is limited to integers below 65,536.

Comment: I don't understand the - '0'

Comment: The sane answer to a question in an embedded space!

Comment: @ConradC It converts the digit (a character) into a small integer. `'0'` is the digit (the character, glyph, symbol) that represents the integer `0`, so by subtracting `'0'` from a known digit character, we get its integer representation. C guarantees that the digit characters are encoded in a way that makes this work.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this test program and tell us what it prints.  If you don't have `printf`, figure out *some way* of getting us the same information that this program prints.  (If you don't have `errno`, that part is not as important as the rest of it.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *my_time = "2505";
    char *endptr;
    unsigned long value;

    errno = 0;
    value = strtoul(my_time, &endptr, 10);
    printf("value=%lu endptr=%s delta=%ld errno=%d (%s)\n",
           value, endptr, (long)(endptr - my_time),
           errno, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error 6 undefined reference to `strerror'

I don't think I can "print" on AtmelStudio. It's embedded programming

Comment: If you don't have `strerror` just take that part out.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to convert a string of decimal digits representing a number within the range of the machine's `unsigned long` type to an `unsigned long` value.  For example:

```
unsigned long my_atoul(const char *digits) {
    unsigned long result = 0;
    const char *c = digits;

    while ('0' <= *c && *c <= '9') {
        result = result * 10 + (*(c++) - '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you want additional features (e.g. choice of radix) or different behavior on non-numeric or overlength input then such things can be implemented on top of that basic approach.